# Do I have to "npm run prod" with every commit to master branch?

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, aws-code-deploy

I have a Laravel application with a React front-end, which is deployed into an EC2 instance with `CodeDeploy-Pipeline + Github`.

As I understand, the `npm run prod` scripts from Laravel Mix (Webpack) should minify the desired assets for production mode, which will have the desired compiled assets for live use.

Since my ec2-deployment will be automatically updated after every commit to `master`, and supposing that I'm not including my compiled assets from `npm run dev` - in my case `apps.js and app.css`- taking me to the loop:

Commit from dev branch to master -> npm run prod -> commit master with minified output assets.

Do I have to run "npm run prod" after every commit to the "master" branch?

Neither Laravel Mix nor Laravel docs are very clear about this or give much advice on the procedure, and in general, found little information about this topic. Are there any usual best practices/WoW for this procedure?

Comment: Unless you have a reason to keep the output assets in source control, just don't do the third step of "commit master with minified output assets.". Instead deploy the production ready assets as the last step in your pipeline. Consider the following CI/CD workflow: 1) commit changes to a new branch, 2) create PR, run automated tests via GitHub actions 3) merge into master 4) CodePipeline is initiated which checks out from master, runs `npm run prod` and stores the output files as build artifacts which are then deployed to the server.

Comment: Hey, I couldn't understand 4th step. Who is running the `prod` command? An automated pipeline script? Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Looks like I forgot a bit of info on step 4. AWS CodeBuild would run `npm run prod`. CodePipeline would entail 3 steps 1) Source - checkout the latest code from GitHub 2) Build - which runs the npm scripts and creates the build artifacts, and finally 3) Deploy - which does just that, deploys the artifacts from step 2. Hopefully this clears things up a bit :)

Comment: Woahh... CodeBuild. I have never used that resource. Long research ahead. Everything now clearer, thank you!